(extra virgin) Olive oil: Bad for Tryglicerides?
I have been reading that Olive Oil is heart healthy.
But now here: https://www.cuh.nhs.uk/patient-information/dietary-advice-for-management-of-high-triglycerides/, it says:

Higher fat (should be avoided): Butter, margarine, olive oil,
vegetable oil, lard, suet.

So I am confused.
Does olive oil raise triglycerides? If Olive Oil were bad for triglycerides I don't think it would be advised for hear healthy diet, am I wrong?
Again here: https://www.health.harvard.edu/nutrition/is-extra-virgin-olive-oil-extra-healthy, it says olive oil is good:

Many studies continue to confirm the health benefits of the
Mediterranean diet, which cuts the risk of heart disease and stroke.

Now I am confused.
